# App button enters selection event twice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button

When I click on my app button, it goes into the selection event handler twice. Any idea why?

### Front end code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" 
                                        Text="New"
                                        x:Name="addIconButton"
                                        Click="addIconButton_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

### Back end code of main:

**Constructor:**

```
addIconButton = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
addIconButton.Click +=new EventHandler(addIconButton_Click);
```

**Event handler:**

```
private void addIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("enters addIcon Main");
    Note note = new Note();
    note.Modified = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    if (note != null)
    {
        Settings.NotesList.Add(note);
        //Settings.NotesList[0] = note;
    }
    Settings.CurrentNoteIndex = 0;
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.XAML",UriKind.Relative));

    //DetailsPage mynewPage = new DetailsPage(); 
    //this.Content = mynewPage;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Click="addIconButton_Click" //in your Front-end code
```

Then,

```
addIconButton.Click +=new EventHandler(addIconButton_Click);
```

Haven't you just added the click handler twice?

Comment: If I don't add:   addIconButton = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];   then i get a null exception error..

Comment: Remove the `Click="addIconButton_Click"` from your front-end code.